# Outlook email format changes when forwarded, How to format in such a way its not modified

Tags: html-email

The automated outlook emails using pywin32 and plain HTML were great till people started using it for forwarding and reply, Once you forward  all the HTML formats are getting stripped and the borders of the table suddenly disappears. The way around is to go to your outlook settings and disable the option "Reduce message size by removing format information not necessary for the message".

The question is how to format the email so that it wont be lost when forwarded and make the format information necessary for the message ?

Comment: No one has found a way to do this yet. Outlooks the painful of them all. It changes the whole code as soon as you press forward. There was another question like this sometime ago as well but no one had an answer for it.

Comment: Hi Syfer, thanks for your feed back, I have found out a work around though,  It is observed that outlook is stripping of those styles which are defined in style block, If the styles are defined embedded in <table> <tr> tags its escaping the stripping. As of now I have taken this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out a work around though, It is observed that outlook is stripping of those styles which are defined in style block, If the styles are defined embedded in   tags its escaping the stripping. As of now I have taken this approach

Comment: Its not  much of a walkaround but normal way of coding emails. Even though 95 percent of emails now support CSS in head its recommended (by the likes of Litmus, Campaign Monitor, Mail Chimp and others) to always in-line your CSS. Like i said above Outlook will still strip out/change your HTML to meet its standard (like stripping out media queries).